# Why doesn't comb pull paper?

Tags: static

I remember doing this as a kid and I also remember that I couldn't do it recently (I still can't do it), no matter how much I rub my ruler or comb against my hair or a blanket it still doesn't move paper even the slightest bit, why?

Is there some engineering method to predict whether materials being rubbed together will create static electricity?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about playing with static electricity.

Comment: You should probably ask this at [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Maybe, but it says electrical engineering and as I am studying static electricity in basics of electrical engineering I thought I should post this question here.

Comment: Even though [physics.se] is probably a better fit for this question, [our help](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that questions about 'the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces' are on-topic.

Comment: If you rub different dielectric materials together, you can generate charges on the materials. Modern combs are made to be static dissipative, since (AFIAK) creating of static is *not* considered a positive feature in most plastic hair comb marketing circles.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you now have a comb made from a different material, and/or your hair is more greasy.

Comment: So it depends which material it's made of?Interesting.

Comment: It used to be that most combs were made of hard rubber, an excellent insulator and extremely durable. Unfortunately, nowadays most combs are made of cheap plastic, which is inferior in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with wet or damp hair and high humidity does not help either. Stop sweating!

Answer (score 0):

Because Homeland Security has mandated that since a hard rubber comb can be used as a high voltage igniter for sensitive primary explosives, all combs must now be filled with dissipative material so that when the comb is held, any electric charge accumulated by combing through hair will be harmlessly diverted into the human body.

**;)**

Comment: Really? Is it too much to ask for a reference that supports your claim? +1 anyway

Comment: It will also fail if the comb emits high levels of ionizing radiation.

Comment: Ricardo: Gee, I thought I read it somewhere... ;)

Comment: Ricardo: BTW, thanks for the up-vote. :-)